# Not adhering to Google Play Developer Program policies

Tags: android, react-native

All I changed on my android app is the app icon and I my update got rejected and the reason is "Not adhering to Google Play Developer Program policies"
Please anyone with necessary information should pls help out.

Comment: Seems you broke one of these policies https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

Comment: Then is probably my App-icon, that is the only modification I made to the app.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I changed the app's icon and my app's update was rejected. Can I ask you how you solved the problem? You added new information to your app's privacy policy?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you get detailed information and instructions on your email linked to google account. perform required changes then:

1- go to google play console.

2- hit "send for review" button in publishing overview section.

3-wait for approval.